# No Action Performed when clicking on jbutton

Tags: java, swing, class, object, jbutton

I am creating a Swing application. I have created a class named `Drone` and made its object in another class named `UserAccount`. At the `JButton` I am calling the getter of the Drone class using `userAccount` but there is no action performed. Why is it happening?

This is the code of Drone class

```
private int x;
private int y;
private String text;
private int a;
private int b;
private String text1;
private int c;
private int d;
private String text2;

public Drone() {
x= 10;
y=150;
a=10;
b=150;
c=1000;
d=150;
text="Drone";
text1="Factory";
text2="Hospital";
    setSize(1070,300);
}

@Override
public void paint(Graphics g) {
    g.setColor(Color.white);
    g.fillRect(0, 0, 1070, 300);
    g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    g.drawString(text, x, y);
    System.out.println(x + "" + y);

    g.drawString(text1, a, b);

    g.drawString(text2, c, d);

}

public void factory() throws InterruptedException{
    while(true){
        while(a<=getWidth()){
            b=getHeight()/2;
            repaint();
            Thread.sleep(1000000);
        }
    }
}

public void Hospital() throws InterruptedException{
    while(true){
        while(c<=getWidth()){
            d=getHeight()/2;
            repaint();
            Thread.sleep(1000000);
        }
    }
}

public void start() throws InterruptedException{
    while(true){
        while(x <= getWidth()-50){
            x++;
            y = getHeight()/2;
            repaint();
            Thread.sleep(150);
        }
        while(x >= 0){
            x--;
            y = getHeight()/2;
            repaint();
            Thread.sleep(150);
        }
        break;
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException{
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Drone Movement");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.HIDE_ON_CLOSE);
    Drone drone = new Drone();
    frame.getContentPane().add(drone);
    frame.setSize(1070,300);
    frame.setLocation(180,200);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    drone.start();
    drone.factory();
    drone.Hospital();
}
```

I am calling this class at the `actionPerformed` of `JButton` present in a `JPanel`

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    userAccount.getDrone();

}
```

Why there is no action performed here?

Comment: What action? What button? None of the code provides any context into your problem. Consider providing a [runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates your problem. This is not a code dump, but an example of what you are doing which highlights the problem you are having. This will result in less confusion and better responses

Comment: Assuming the `Drone` in a Swing based component, then you really shouldn't be overriding `paint`, but instead, prefer `paintComponent`. You should also be calling the `super` paint method in order to maintain the existing paint chain contract

Comment: We may never know...

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing adding the action listener.

Inside the Drone class where the JButton as created should have something like

```
JButton button = new JButton("button");
button.addActionListener(this);
```

where the Drone implements ActionListener.

But base on what you said, the JButton has the actionPerformed which I assume you are extending the JButton to implement ActionListener and implemented the actionPerformed method, then the code should be

```
public class MyButton extends JButton implements ActionListener {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
        //TODO implement your action here
    }
```

Then in your Drone, you should have something like

```
MyButton button = new MyButton();
button.addActionListener(button); // the button itself instead of the this
```

Comment: Based on what little we have of the OP's code, I would say they've set up the UI using Netbeans form designer...